# How to set different images in WMS by zoom level in Geoserver?

Tags: zooming, tiff, geoserver, wms

How to set different images (same TIF with different size) for some zoom levels?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.

First, layer group and scale dependencies:

- create N separate layers, associate each one with a different set of activation scales in their style (take the raster style, copy, add min and max scale denominators). See also [the documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html)
- make each layer "non advertised"
- lump them all toghether in a layer group (or if you are on 2.11, skip the non advertised bit above and just create a "opaque container" layer group)

Second approach, use image pyramid:

- Download and install the pyramid extension
- Put each file in a different folder, naming them 0, 1, 2, 3, ....
- Point the image pyramid to the parent folder, it will automatically figure out the image resolutions and setup scale switches based on that
- If that does not satisfy you, go and tweak the pyramid property file in the parent folder